# how can i find CSS of a site

Tags: css

how can i download all CSS used in a site, for example im interested to www.MSN.ca and i want to know about style-sheets yous in MSN !

thanks

Comment: get Firebug and click the `CSS` tab to see all the stylesheets applied to that site.

Comment: but fireBug just show me the class name, not class content, right ?

Comment: Opery Dragonfly also works perfectly to show (and debug) CSS code. Though if you want to understand the CSS of a site like MSN.ca, you will have a long journey ahead of you.

Answer (score 1):

- http://www.httrack.com/
- http://spiderzilla.mozdev.org/
- http://chrispederick.com/work/web-developer/

Answer (score 0):

Look at the html.

Comment: ..and look for inline css or link tags

Comment: I thought that would be implicit.